# Get user instance from profile model __str__ in django

Tags: python, django

I have this simple model:

```
class Profile(models.Model):
bio             = models.CharField(max_length=300, blank=False)
location        = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=
edu             = models.CharField(max_length=250, blank=True, null=False)
profession      = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)
profile_image   = models.ImageField(
    upload_to=upload_image, blank=True, null=False)

def __str__(self):
    try: 
        return str(self.pk)
    except:
        return ""
```

and a User model:

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser, UserTimeStamp):
    first_name  = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=False, null=False)
    email       = models.EmailField(unique=True, blank=False, null=False)
    profile     = models.OneToOneField(Profile, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    uuid        = models.UUIDField(
        db_index=True,
        default=uuid_lib.uuid4,
        editable=False
    )
    is_admin    = models.BooleanField(default=False, blank=False, null=False)
    is_staff    = models.BooleanField(default=False, blank=False, null=False)
    is_active   = models.BooleanField(default=True, blank=False, null=False)

    objects     = UserManager()

    USERNAME_FIELD = "email"

    def has_perm(self, perm, obj=None):
        return True

    def has_module_perms(self, perm_label):
        return True
```

As you can see in User model I have a OneToOneField to Profile.

but in Profile model I can't access user instance to just use its email in **str** method. something like this:

```
def __str__(self):
    return self.user.email
```

How can I do this? sometime these relations are confusing to me.

**UPDATED**

Yes self.user.email works well. but the problem is something else.
I have two type of users. users and teachers. 
and each of them has field profile in their model. so if I say:

```
def __str__(self):
    return self.user.email
```

It just returns email of user instances. what about teachers?

Comment: Why can't you? What happens?

Comment: Thanks dear Daniel. Actually my code was broken somewhere else. and yeah you right self.user.email works. as I explained to @hassanzadeh.sd there is something else come in to play after that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

user model:

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser, UserTimeStamp):
    profile     = models.OneToOneField(Profile, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='user_profile')
```

teacher model:

```
class Teacher(AbstractBaseUser, UserTimeStamp):
    profile     = models.OneToOneField(Profile, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='teacher_profile')
```

profile model:

```
def __str__(self):
    if hasattr(self, 'user_profile'):
          # profile belong to user
          print(self.user_profile.pk)
    elif hasattr(self, 'teacher_profile'):
          # profile belong to teacher
          print(self.teacher_profile.pk)
```

Comment: Thanks solved. except that instead of print() we must use return to display.